# Self hosted material icons ver 4 for Angular projects

Tags: angular, google-material-icons

Some web based projects are designed to run internally inside a local net, without access to the open internet. From security prospective, quite logical. For such internal apps the designer needs to self host the angular/google material icons. When installed using npm, the old icons show, but the new ones do not. The npm version is quite old and has not been updated for years.

The official doc to: [Setup Method 2. Self hosting](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_icons#setup_method_2_self_hosting) will point to:  [icon font](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/font), however I do not see any of the required woff/woff2 files.
This is not a complete answer.

In my search for a solution, I only see a bunch of half baked answers and a group of (rightfully) frustrated seekers.

Would any one please provide a straight forward and actually working - complete set of steps to get the latest material icons working on self hosted background?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Host Google Material Icon Fonts locally: [Here](https://thecodeframework.com/host-google-material-icon-fonts-locally-in-angular-in-5-simple-steps/)

The simplest way:

1. npm i material-icons  (Latest icon fonts and CSS for self-hosting material design icons.)
2. Styles:

A) In your angular.json:

```
  "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": ...,
          "options": {
          ....
          "styles": [
              ...
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
              ...
            ],
             
            "scripts": []
          },
```

or
B) in your styles.scss:

```
@import '~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

Comment: npm installs version:  material-icons@1.2.1;
Your link leads to folder:  https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/font.  Check it out, it does not contain the woff/woff2 files referenced in: '~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'